# How to change filter queryset depends on user

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I am using `django-filter` and I have two models `CustomUser` and `Shop`. How to change filter choices queryset so that user(`request.user`) can filter only his shops?

## User

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    shop = models.ManyToManyField(Shop, blank=True, related_name='custom_user')
```

## Shop

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(_('Address'), unique=True, max_length=64, blank=False, null=False, db_index=True)
```

## filters.py

```
shops = Shop.objects.filter(is_active=True)
SHOP_CHOICES = [('All', 'All')]
for x in shops:
    SHOP_CHOICES.append((x.address, x))
SHOP_CHOICES = tuple(SHOP_CHOICES)


class ShopFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    address = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=SHOP_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = Shop
        fields = ['address']
```

views.py

```
f = ShopFilter(request.GET)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the queryset before it's returned using the `qs` method.

See [Filtering the primary `qs.](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#filtering-the-primary-qs)

So in your case, you should be able to say:

```
@property
def qs(self):
    parent = super().qs
    owner = getattr(self.request, 'user', None)

    return parent.filter(custom_user=owner)
```

Haven't tested this, but this is definitely the method if you want to make any modifications to the query.